# Why use Lemma before NER

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition, lemmatization, part-of-speech

I am using Stanford Annotators NER, and I noticed that Lemma is a prerequisite for NER. Can someone please explain, why is that. More importantly, why should I also do POS before doing NER ?

The dependencies of Stanford Annotators are given [here](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/dependencies.html)

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the NER models we distribute, I don't see that any of them have the "useLemmas" flag in their settings.  That being said it is possible for an NER model to use lemmas as a feature, so the `ner` annotator has that as a requirement.

The lemma annotator requires part-of-speech tags, so that is why that is required.

Answer (score 0):

POS is basic process with help other of function....like
POS use to tag your data and after that it get easy for NER to process only on Noun tag and save lot of processing power..
and not sure about lemma..may be it clear data and change with root word so like ,same word in past or future tense process once